# Java ~ User by user

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

I would like the user to provide data by scanner and add it to list. Later, I want to get the size of this list and for example user name, last name. I'm still trying to work with constructors and exceptions and now I want to try to put data from user.

It's Human Service which checks constructors, and if the name has less than 3 letters and lastname less than 5 letters will throw an exception.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HumanService {
    List<Human> humans;

    public HumanService() {
        humans = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addHuman(String name, String lastName) throws HumanNameWrongFormat, HumanLastNameWrongFormat {
        if(HumanValidator.humanValidatorName(name) && HumanValidator.humanValidatorLastName(lastName)) {
            Human human = new Human(sizeOfList(), name, lastName);
            humans.add(human);
        }
    }

    public int sizeOfList() {
        return humans.size();
    }

    public Human getHumanByLastName(String lastName) throws HumanNotFoundException {
        for (Human human : humans) {
            if (human.getLastName().equals(lastName)) {
                return human;
            }
        }
        throw new HumanNotFoundException(lastName + " not found");
    }

    public Human getHumanById (Integer id) throws HumanNotFoundException {
        for (Human human : humans) {
            if (human.getId().equals(id)) {
                return human;
            }
        }
        throw new HumanNotFoundException(id + " not found");
    }
}
```

I want to get data by user to list.
For example.
Please give me your name and last name.
Here is your name and last name by scanner and that will be added to list and checked.

This is also my main class.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws HumanNotFoundException {
        HumanService humanService = new HumanService();

        try {
            humanService.addHuman("John", "Walker");
            humanService.addHuman("Steve", "Williams");
            humanService.addHuman("Gregor", "Wroten");
        }
        catch (HumanNameWrongFormat | HumanLastNameWrongFormat e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(humanService.sizeOfList());

        try {
            humanService.getHumanByLastName("Wroten");
        }
        catch (HumanNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you can use `Scanner` to get all the required user names and add them to the list for further processing

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Human> humans = new ArrayList();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please give your first name");
            String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please give your last name");
            String lastName = scanner.nextLine();
            humans.add(new Human(firstName, lastName)); // use your humanService here
            boolean breakOut = false;
            String input;
            do {
                System.out.println("Do you want to enter more names? (Y/N)");
                input = scanner.nextLine();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    breakOut = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. try again");
                }
            } while (!breakOut);
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(humans);
    }
}
```

I am assuming you have two fields `firstName`, `lastName` in `Human`

```
class Human {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Human(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "first name " + firstName + " and last name " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
Please give your first name
John
Please give your last name
Smith
Do you want to enter more names? (Y/N)
y
Please give your first name
Will
Please give your last name
Smith
Do you want to enter more names? (Y/N)
n
```

Output:

```
[first name John and last name Smith, first name Will and last name Smith]
```

In the above code, `replace` the `list` with your `humanService` to add the `humans`